# CakePHP: How can I customize the labels for multiple checkboxes

Tags: cakephp, checkbox, label

I've done a lot of searching but havent been able to solve this yet. I have a user registration form where the user can select a number of store branches as favourites upon registration. I have this relationship set up as a HABTM.

I am able to display the store branches as multiple checkboxes, but I need to display the store name (the store branches belongs to store names) along with the branch name in the label for each checkbox. Something like:

Levi's - Canal Walk

where Canal Walk is the branch name, and Levi's is the store name (coming from a different table)

Can anyone please share some insight on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it might work (or help you along the right path):

```
$branches = $this->Branch->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Branch.id', 'CONCAT(Store.name, " - ", Branch.name)'),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'stores',
            'alias' => 'Store',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Branch.store_id' => 'Store.id')
        )
    )
));
```

Set this in your controller, or keep things DRY by placing it in your model in a function such as `findFullList()`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would do all of this in the view.  If your HABTM relationship is setup correctly, a query of the Store model should work something like this:

```
$stores = $this->Store->findAll();
//Returns
Array([0] => Array(
    'Store' => array(),
    'Branch' => array(
        [0] => array(),
        [1] => array()...));
```

Then pass the $stores variable into the view, and iterate through it with a double nested loop.

```
foreach($stores as $store){  
        foreach($store['Branch'] as $branch){
            //Code to output checkbox by using $branch['name']
        }
    }
```